# template.$(selector) not working Meteor

Tags: meteor

I just discover that it is a good pattern to restrict the DOM search to current template instead of `document`, so I was starting to replace all `document.querySelector()` by `template.find()` and jquery `$(selector)` by `template.$(selector)`.
Inside events everything works great but then in this code (`onRendered`) it just doesn't work and I get an: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'template.$')` in the console:

```
Template.icons.onRendered(function () {
    template.$('.demo-default').tooltipster({
        offsetY: 2,
         theme: 'tooltipster-shadow'
    })
});
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside lifecycle events callbacks such as `onCreated`, `onRendered` and `onDestroyed`, the current template instance is bound to the `this` keyword.

Simply replace `template` (which is undefined in this context by the way) by `this` :

```
Template.icons.onRendered(function () {
  this.$('.demo-default').tooltipster({
    offsetY: 2,
    theme: 'tooltipster-shadow'
  })
});
```

Comment: You're right, but then the question is: where should I use template.$? Inside helpers?...

Comment: @PauloJaneiro only in events I think, where you have a function e.g. `Template.MyTemplate.events({ 'click .my-button': function (event, template) { ... }});`. Inside helpers you can use `Template.instance()` instead.